# How do I read a cell below a cell with a keyword in it

Tags: python, excel

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_loc = sheet.cell_value(i,3)
    if findWholeWord('People')(row_loc):

        print (row_loc)
```

I have this code for finding the names of analysts in Bloomberg terminal emails, the names of the analysts are always below a cell with the word 'people' and I want to know how to read that cell below with the name in it?

Also, I need to stay in the (i,3) column because that is where the messages are, meaning using next() is tricky.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is always below the cell where the string 'People' is contained you can simply get the cell by incrementing the row by 1

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_loc = sheet.cell_value(i,3)
    if 'People' in row_loc:
        analyst_name = sheet.cell_value(i+1,3)
```

Comment: thank you very much, only just starting out with python so not very handy at it. Very helpful!